# Background color of an svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to change the INSIDE background color of a heart-shaped svg but with normal background it overflows and with fill it changes the border not the inside, any tips on how i might achive what i am looking for?

```css
.heart {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heart:active {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg class="heart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 471.701 471.701" style="enable-background:new 0 0 471.701 471.701;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path d="M433.601,67.001c-24.7-24.7-57.4-38.2-92.3-38.2s-67.7,13.6-92.4,38.3l-12.9,12.9l-13.1-13.1   c-24.7-24.7-57.6-38.4-92.5-38.4c-34.8,0-67.6,13.6-92.2,38.2c-24.7,24.7-38.3,57.5-38.2,92.4c0,34.9,13.7,67.6,38.4,92.3   l187.8,187.8c2.6,2.6,6.1,4,9.5,4c3.4,0,6.9-1.3,9.5-3.9l188.2-187.5c24.7-24.7,38.3-57.5,38.3-92.4   C471.801,124.501,458.301,91.701,433.601,67.001z M414.401,232.701l-178.7,178l-178.3-178.3c-19.6-19.6-30.4-45.6-30.4-73.3   s10.7-53.7,30.3-73.2c19.5-19.5,45.5-30.3,73.1-30.3c27.7,0,53.8,10.8,73.4,30.4l22.6,22.6c5.3,5.3,13.8,5.3,19.1,0l22.4-22.4   c19.6-19.6,45.7-30.4,73.3-30.4c27.6,0,53.6,10.8,73.2,30.3c19.6,19.6,30.3,45.6,30.3,73.3   C444.801,187.101,434.001,213.101,414.401,232.701z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issues & Solutions**

1. svg's `path` is an outline only
2. apply fill to the `path` instead of `svg`

```css
.heart {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heart:active path {
  fill: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg class="heart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 471.701 471.701" style="enable-background:new 0 0 471.701 471.701;" xml:space="preserve">
     <path d="m433.601,68.66767c-24.7,-24.7 -57.4,-38.2 -92.3,-38.2s-67.7,13.6 -92.4,38.3l-12.9,12.9l-13.1,-13.1c-24.7,-24.7 -57.6,-38.4 -92.5,-38.4c-34.8,0 -67.6,13.6 -92.2,38.2c-24.7,24.7 -38.3,57.5 -38.2,92.4c0,34.9 13.7,67.6 38.4,92.3l187.8,187.8c2.6,2.6 6.1,4 9.5,4c3.4,0 6.9,-1.3 9.5,-3.9l188.2,-187.5c24.7,-24.7 38.3,-57.5 38.3,-92.4c0.1,-34.9 -13.4,-67.7 -38.1,-92.4z" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```